# Spark Java union/concat Multiple Dataframe/sql in loop

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement wherein I want to union/concat multiple dataframes. overall we have around 14000 such dataframes/sql which we generate at run time and then union all before writing to hive. I tried two ways but both are very slow. Is there any way to optimize below or run them in parallel.
Note I need the solution only in spark java.

Psuedo code

1st way:

```java
Dataset dfunion = null;
for (int i = 0; i <= 14000; i++) {
  String somesql = "select columns from table where conditions(depending on each loop)"
  if (i == 1)
    dfunion = spark.sql(somesql);
  else{
    dfunion = dfunion.union(spark.sql(somesql)); 
  }
}
dfunion.writetohive
```

2nd way:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= 14000; i++) {
  String somesql = "select columns from table where conditions(depending on each loop)"
  if (i == 1)
    spark.sql(somesql).write.mode(overwrite).parquet;
  else {
    spark.sql(somesql).write.mode(append).parquet;
  }
}
Dataset dfread = spark.read.parquet().writetohive;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why can't you generate conditions and filter the table at once

Comment: I cant. As i said table and condition will keep on changing based on each loop. Even if i generate conditions and run with or conditions it is slow.

Comment: I mean you can collect filter conditions by using for loop and then collectively apply- `select * from table where <collected filter condition from for loop>`

Comment: I got your point which is fine for a single table. But in my case for each loop table may get  change and at the end i have to  union/concat the dataframe.

Comment: how do you get to know which condition to apply on which table? do you have any mapping? since you are talking about multiple table and not single, are they having same schema or each time you will select the same schema and then do a union?

Comment: Yes we do have mapping but we also get few column values runtime from some other rules table and those are used in where condition along with other condition. Yes table schema are same. its just that queries are different for each iteration. Do you know anything if we can run spark sql queries in parallel?